# How to remove Space line from text file in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

How to remove space line from text file and start next line in C# using StreamReader.

My code is,

```
try
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("OrderDetails.txt")))
    {
        string sFileName = Server.MapPath("OrderDetails.txt");
        using (StreamReader StreamReader1 = new StreamReader(sFileName))
        {
            sb.Append(StreamReader1.ReadToEnd());
            StreamReader1.Close();
            try
            {
                if (Session["Package1"].ToString() == "true")
                {
                    sb.Replace("{Package1}", "Package1");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Replace("{Package1}", null);
                }

                if (Session["Package2"].ToString() == "true")
                {
                    sb.Replace("{Package2}", "Package2");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Replace("{Package2}", null);
                }

                if (Session["Package3"].ToString() == "true")
                {
                    sb.Replace("{Package3}", "Package3");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Replace("{Package3}", null);
                }
               
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return "";
}
```

I am getting following output when Session["Package2"] is "false",

> Package1
>
> // I am getting line spce here
>
> Package3

I want output like this when Session["Package2"] is "false",

> Package1
>
> Package3

I am using VS2008(3.5).

Comment: What is the reason to check bool values in such ugly manner `if (Session["Package2"].ToString() == "true")` not  `if (Session["Package2"])` ?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to skip lines with spaces only? Use `ReadLine` instead to advance the reader to the next line and check if it's empty:

```
string line;
using (StreamReader StreamReader1 = new StreamReader(sFileName))
{
    while ((line = StreamReader1.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim()))
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: IsNullOrWhiteSpace showing error because i am using 3.5 verson

Answer (score 0):

In your StringBuilder you append everything from the file including the characters used to represent the newline. But when you try your replacement code, you replace only the characters of the string excluding the newline. This newline remains in the StringBuilder buffer and is causing the empty line.

I would try

```
......
string replacement = (Session["Package1"].ToString() == "true" ? 
                                          "Package1" + Environment.NewLine, "");
sb.Replace("{Package1}" + Environment.NewLine, replacement);
......
```